# How to align text boxes while keeping layout

Tags: video, premiere-pro

I'm pretty new to Premiere Pro, and can't get my text (separate boxes, same layer) to align properly. I made a Photoshop mockup. Say you start with this.

[image]

Here is what is happening

[image]

Here is what I would like to happen.

[image]

Basically just have the text go to the vertical center of the screen while keeping the original layout.